# Get post from meta_key and meta_value

Tags: post-meta, sql

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = $param1 AND meta_value = $param2
```

I am facing one problem:

I don't know how to do that **sql** code with wordpress functionalities. I have read the manual to `get_posts()` etc. (though I might have missed something), but I haven't found a way to implement this yet.

Can you help me and show me a way or a hint.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can get using this using SQL

```
global $wpdb;

// For single record
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = $param1 AND meta_value = $param2");

// For multiple records
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = $param1 AND meta_value = $param2" );
```

> Use this for query

```
 $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10, // -1 for all posts
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'your_meta_key',
               'value' => 'your_meta_value',
               'compare' => '=',
           )
       )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: This is good but i think my instructor dont want me to use sql, but instead use wp functions like `get_post()`. Do you know a function that translates to this sql?

Comment: i updated answer please check

Comment: if the answer is correct. please tick it correct. Thanks

Comment: actually both answers are correct ... its a dilemma

Answer (score 0):

Try Like:

```
global $wpdb;

$post = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = $param1 AND meta_value = $param2');
```

Using Wordpress default method:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'YOUR KEY',
            'value'   => 'YOUR VALUE',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Then print result of `$post` like `print_r($post)` and check have you get your `post_id` or not. Please let me know if any query.

Hope it will help!

Comment: This is good but i think my instructor dont want me to use sql, but instead use wp functions like get_post(). Do you know a function that translates to this sql?

Comment: I have update my answer so please try and let me know if any query

Comment: @Anew1 Please try `get_post` method.